# ng2-tag-input 'tag-input' is not a known element Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am attempting to install ng2-tag-input into my ionic app.

After successfully installing it with npm install, here is my app.component.ts

```
import {TagInputModule} from 'ng2-tag-input';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
    declarations   : [
        MyApp,
    ],
    imports        : [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        PagesModule,
        TagInputModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
            // DeepLinker
            // http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/
            links: [
                {component: ProfilePage, name: 'Profile', segment: 'profile/:username'},
                {component: PhotoCardComponent, name: 'Photo', segment: 'photo/:id'},
                {component: ChatMessagePage, name: 'Chat', segment: 'chat/:id'},
                {component: TermsPage, name: 'Terms', segment: 'terms'},
            ]
        })
    ],
    exports        : [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        TagInputModule
    ],
```

Then when I run

```
ionic serve
```

The following issue happens

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'tag-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'tag-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'tag-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
                </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
            [ERROR ->]<tag-input [(ngModel)]="items"></tag-input>
```

I am not sure what I did wrong. Can anyone help point it out?

Comment: what module does the component with `tag-input` belong to?

Answer (score 0):

add FormModule into import into your app.component.ts.
  `[(ngModule)]` so need to import FormModule.

Answer (score 0):

According to the authors, the package has been renamed to ngx-tags-input.
So, you should install it with `npm install ngx-tags-input --save`.
Then, import the library like this:

```
import { TagsInputModule } from 'ngx-tags-input/dist';
```